# Ctrl modifier on PgUp ignored in linux console

Tags: linux, vim

I'm running Linux in single user text mode ([as described here](https://superuser.com/a/1177675/583279)). `Ctrl+PgUp` and `Ctrl+PgDn` don't behave as expected. Using `cat -v -` to show the terminal codes, I see that `PgUp` and `Ctrl+PgUp` both produce the same code `^[[5~`. Doing the same thing in graphical mode I see `PgUp` => `^[[5~` and `Ctrl+PgUp` => `^[[5;5~` (and both keys work as expected). Therefore I conjecture:

- It's not a hardware problem
- The mapping `PgUp` => `^[[5~` is working as intended
- The problem is that `Ctrl+PgUp` looks like `PgUp` once it reaches the terminal.

For my use case (Vim) I can configure `PgUp` to be treated as `Ctrl+PgUp`, but if possible I'd like them to have different behaviours.

Is there some configuration I can edit to fix this? Does anything modify the character sequences before they reach the terminal?

More notes from further investigation:

- Rather than booting to text mode, I can reproduce this just by dropping to tty1 (`Ctrl+Alt+F1`).
- I can reproduce it on a different machine.
- Following dirkt's suggestion I ran `echo $TERM` and got `linux`.

Comment: On my console, the terminal type is `linux` (`echo $TERM`), and `infocmp linux` shows that `knp` (next page) and `kpp` (previous page) are bound to `ESC [ 6 ~` and `ESC [ 5 ~`, respectively. So this is a "feature" of the linux text console, though I am not sure exactly which level is responsible, and how to configure it. Maybe trying to configure vim to recognize the escape sequences is simpler.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for the comment; I didn't know about `infocmp`. However I think the problem is not what `PgUp` maps to, but that `PgUp` and `Ctrl+PgUp` are indistinguishable. I'll make an edit to clarify.

Comment: They are likely indistinguishable because the linux text console translates *both* to `knp` and `kpp`. You can easily check the lowest layers with `evtest`, and my guess is that the `Ctrl` key will be clearly visible, and the translation happens after the keyboard events leave the kernel input layer and enter the console line discipline (or whereever that translation actually sits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This useful answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116630/245634) led me to a solution. My default keymap (obtained from `sudo dumpkeys`) contained

```
keycode 104 = Prior
...
string Prior = "\033[5~"
```

I added

```
control keycode 104 = F105
...
string F105 = "\033[5;5~"
```

and similarly for <kbd>PgDn</kbd>. Note that the alias can't be an arbitrary string; it has to be one of the keysyms listed by `sudo dumpkeys -l`, so I picked F105 which was unused.

Now `cat -v -` shows `^[[5;5~` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> as in graphical mode. Vim still didn't react as expected (I'm not sure why, since it works in graphical mode) but at least <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> produces a different control sequence from <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, which I remap in my `.vimrc` as usual:

```
nnoremap ^[[5;5~ :tabp<Enter>
```